# I can't find Java_org_opencv_objdetect_CascadeClassifier for opencv android sdk in jni folder?

Tags: android, opencv, java-native-interface

Have all of source code been release? My opencv version is 2.4.9. I have reorganize my project,write
Android.mk by myself.Finally I run face-detection demo and I got "Native method not found: org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier.CascadeClassifier_1:" something like this. I have search the whole opencv source but I can't find Java_org_opencv_objdetect_CascadeClassifier_CascadeClassifier_1 or anything like this.

Comment: from cv android sdk Mat.java,those native methods's source code not found:
// C++: Mat::Mat()
private static native long n_Mat();

// C++: Mat::Mat(int rows, int cols, int type)
private static native long n_Mat(int rows, int cols, int type);

// C++: Mat::Mat(Size size, int type)
private static native long n_Mat(double size_width, double size_height, int type);

Answer (score 0):

I dont know the specific question by you.But Native method not found is the common error.Possible reasons for native method not found are

1.)the type mismatch in the c++ function name and java function name.The c++ function name must be in
   the format Java_PackageName_classname_functionname

2.)you are calling function before initilization of opencv library.

If you are again not able to find please share your code

Comment: Thanks! And the two points you said I am sure is right.Now my problem is I can't find the native code for cv android sdks,such as below(from Mat.java):
// C++: Mat::Mat()
private static native long n_Mat();

// C++: Mat::Mat(int rows, int cols, int type)
private static native long n_Mat(int rows, int cols, int type);

// C++: Mat::Mat(Size size, int type)
private static native long n_Mat(double size_width, double size_height, int type);

Comment: Do you use mat object initialization in oncreate method?please Dont do that.In onResume method the opencv library got called.After that you can call Mat object because its using opencv library from opencv manager.Opencv manager is different app which must be installed for async initialization of your app

Answer (score 0):

the sample problem puzzled me long time.

(my apk running well as using Android studio install it,when using Android.mk to complie in Android System (put source file to packages/apps/"apk name"))

I just replay"libopencv_java3.so"file by "\OpenCV-android-sdk\sdk\native\libs\arm64-v8a\libopencv_java3.so",because this two files size is different,then this problem is solved.

as a result , this problem should be caused by "libopencv_java3.so"